# How to 301 redirect Domain1.com to Domain1.NL and excluding https://Domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

"Im busy for a while now solving the following issue:

I have a http://domain.com with an SSL certificate on it. 
I want to redirect this domain.com to my dutch domain.nl.

But: I also want to avoid/exclude the  from redirecting ( I need SSL for Facebook Apps)
OR
redirect domain.com except

Sofar i have added this to my htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks to all for giving it a helping hand.

Greetings

Michel

Comment: The code seems to look fine. What is working/not working with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your browser cache and restart the browser.

**Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess** through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Once you make sure it's working fine change 302 to 301 in above rule.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be on it first thing tomorrow but wanted to make noticed i read your answer.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know how it goes. btw I upvoted your question just for your courtesy comment :)

Comment: Hey !! Could not wait till tomorrow. Executed and yeah it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know that, can you accept this answer to close this Q&A :)